# Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio evaluation period has expired

Tags: sql-server

We have SQL Server 2014 Enterprise edition. SSMS was installed with the server itself, not separately. The SQL Server `SERVERPROPERTY('LicenseType')` shows DISABLED.

We are getting below error while working with SSMS.

> Your Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio evaluation period has expired. You can get a key to extend your trial by registering this copy of Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio online and Prompt to enter the product key.

How it can be fixed? Any help.

Comment: see this may help you http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/28867/sql-server-2008-r2-management-studio-evaluation-period-has-expired

Comment: has your evaluation period expired?

Comment: We have same version installed in different environment and rest are working fine. The SSMS was installed with the SQL Server package. How can I confirm if the period has expired?

Comment: @p2k obviously you installed an evaluation version of SQL Server. This message doesn't appear in any other case.

Comment: Remove SSMS 2014 and install the [latest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx) SSMS version. SSMS is now a separate free product

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos - Installing new version of SSMS will be enough? Or complete SQL Server re-installation required (wondering why it is for only SSMS). I am using Windows Server 2012 R2. An installer was provided by a infrastructure team and there was no product key required during the installation (long back).

Comment: SSMS is a separate product now. Of course the *evaluation* version of SQL Server that you installed will also expire soon, if it hadn't already. BTW SQL Server 2016 Developer edition is free too, and has the same features as Enterprise. No need to use evaluation or 180-day Technet editions (which is what probably happened)

Answer (score 1):

Since 2016 SQL Server Management Studio is a separate, free  product with monthly updates. You can download the latest version [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx). It works with previous SQL Server versions so there's no need to worry about missing features.